# Modelagem Categorias e Subcategorias

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Estou modelando um banco de dados relacionado a e-commerce e estou com uma dúvida na modelagem das tabelas de categorias e subcategorias dos produtos.

A princípio eu criei duas tabelas uma de `Categoria` e outra de `Subcategoria`. No entanto, achei um [artigo onde o autor diz não ser necessário criar duas tabelas](http://rberaldo.com.br/categorias-e-subcategorias-exemplo-de-modelagem/). O que ele faz basicamente é na mesma tabela incluir o código da categoria no registro que será uma subcategoria.

Quais as vantagens de fazer um modelo com duas tabelas ou uma só, como mencionado no artigo?

Comment: Veja se algo te ajuda aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=categoria%20subcategoria

Comment: Já trabalhei com os dois modelos mas não vi muitas diferenças entre duas ou um tabela.  A única coisa boa de usar somente uma foi a de montar treeview

Answer (score 3):

Necessário não é. A diferença está entre a [normalização dos dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados) e a [desnormalização](http://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/desnormalizacao-e-redundancia-controlada-em-bancos-de-dados-relacionais/?trace=1519021197&source=single) dos dados.

A normalização visa evitar redundância de informações e dar mais consistência aos dados.

Já a desnormalização, visa melhor performance (uma vez que, em algumas situações, uma alta normalização pode causar altos custos de performance).

Optar entre um ou outro, ou mesmo utilizar um pouco de cada, depende de cada projeto (inclusive quantidade de registros, hardware disponível, quantidade de usuários, etc.).

Recomendação de um grande profissional da área de banco de dados:

> **"Normalizar até doer, desnormalizar até funcionar!"**
>
> Jason Couchman, autor do livro: “Oracle 8 Certified Professional DBA Certification Exam Guide"

Existem vários artigos na internet sobre o tema!